# The application freezes when I try to update timestamp column with a placeholder in an Oracle database using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to update 2 columns in an Oracle database using C#. The columns I want to update are `StartTime` i.e. a timestamp and `Name` i.e. string. However when I run my code, the application freezes. I following is my code:

```
public int StartProduction(string serialNr, string empName)
{
    string queryString = "UPDATE RO_EXEMPLAAR_PIM SET PLAKTAFEL_START=systimestamp, STARTED_BY=:startedBy WHERE SERIENR=:serialNr";
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                connection.Open();

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("serialNr", serialNr);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("startedBy", empName);

                da.InsertCommand = command;
                int nrOfRecordsChanged = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return nrOfRecordsChanged;
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1; //which means the try-block was not executed succesfully
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call it in a form as this:

```
if (dh.StartProduction(serialNr, empName) != -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Production started successfully!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Production cannot be started!");
}
```

I looked up online and could not find what is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of application? Desktop? How this function is called?

Comment: @GuruStron a desktop application, it is called in a form

Comment: What is that DataAdapter doing in there? Remove it

Comment: Probably something like your connection is timing out (you just havent waited long enough) or . Your app freezes because you jammed the UI thread, by doing this work syncronously on that thread (whose normal job is to draw the UI - it's quite simple really; a thread runs in a loop like crazy, consuming every message sent to a window. If you stop it from doing that and send it off on some 30 second mission to connect to a DB that halts the thread until the connection fails, then you'll freeze your program for 30s)

Comment: @CaiusJard i removed the data adapter, nothing changed. But how can I not jam the UI thread?

Comment: @CaiusJard it is frozen for 5 minutes..

Comment: "return -1;"  SideNote.    See ->> "DO NOT return error codes"    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing This is a horrible practice.  You are in OO land, not http or sql land.

Comment: Suggest you debug by running a benign query like "SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;",  and see if your connection actually connects.

Comment: @granadaCoder yes my connection string is correct, I can already retrieve data from this table

Comment: I didnt think anything would change with removing the DA, it's just that it has no place in the code; it's dead wood

Comment: If it's frozen for 5 minutes then that's what's going on; either it's waiting to connect, or waiting for a lock to be released or waiting for... You aren't really telling us whether it's a problem or not. I've told you why your app has frozen; your query attempt has started and has not yet stopped and returned. You're doing the work on the UI thread so the app is jammed. Wait for it to complete, or time out. If you want the app to carry on being responsive while it waits for this update to (never) complete, make the call asyncronous; don't jam the UI thread

Comment: make sure you are not missing a "commit;" in your sql-developer or dbvisualizer or something like that. (or somebody on your dev team).  or reboot the server.

Comment: @granadaCoder I just rebooted the database connection, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try a non locking read query like;

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;
```

If that works (proving your connection string works).

Then you probably have a locking issue.

In general: (especially for devs)

Make sure you are not missing a "commit;" in your sql-developer or dbvisualizer or something like that. (or somebody on your dev team).
Running an update without a "commit;" in side these tools will lock a row.

If you can't find the culprit :  a reboot of the server is in order.